# Mount network drive from terminal on Ubuntu running in Windows HyperV VM

Tags: command-line, networking, mount, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu running in Windows HyperV VM.  I have a shared network drive I can reach from the Ubuntu GUI. It has both read and write permissions there.

I need to navigate to this network location from a terminal shell in order to execute a `make` command.

I have no knowledge of the Ubuntu OS or how it works, so basic explicit instructions will be needed.

I tried following [this post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/145191/how-do-i-map-a-drive-network-share-using-the-linux-terminal)

but I get an error along the lines of

```
block device //servername/dir is write-protected, mounting read-only. 
Cannot mount block device //servername/dir read-only.
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the syntax in the example was not correct (at least for what I was trying to do).

The `mount` command that worked was this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o "username=myUserName,password=myPassword" //ip_of_network_destination/dir .
```

the terminal doesn't refresh itself, so you have to close it and open it to reach the newly mounted filesystem, but the drive shows up in the GUI, so you know it stuck.